# Minion Pro: lining figures shown as empty boxes

Tags: minionpro

Setting: Windows 7 64bit, MiKTeX, pdfLaTeX, specifically, I followed [these instructions](http://www86.zippyshare.com/v/CTFSiJje/file.html).

Having re-installed again and again, trying to make sure that I am not missing anything from the installation instructions, I still have the same problem: lining figures are shown as empty boxes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
Normal Text: 0123456789

Math Mode: $0123456789$
\end{document}
```

outputs:

[image]

```
\usepackage[textlf]{MinionPro}
```

option outputs:

[image]

Curious, I tried:

```
\begin{document}
\fonttable{MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa}

\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]

So, at least to my understanding, the lining figures are “there.”

What else should I try? What **might** I be doing wrong? I am frustrated because almost no one else have this problem, so I should be something wrong, and strangely, only the lining figures seem to be the problem.

Comment: For me it works fine (same system as you). Could you check the contents of the `MinionPro.map`? It should contains lines like `MinionPro-Bold-` **lf**` -l1-lgi--base MinionPro-Bold "AutoEnc_irupxkrjzh7fov4222hjskvybc ReEncodeFont" <[a_irupxk.enc <MinionPro-Bold.pfb`(I have 4721 lines like that).

Comment: @Bernard I have lines like: `MinionPro-Bold--lcdfj MinionPro-BoldLCDFJ "" <MinionPro-BoldLCDFJ.pfb
MinionPro-Bold-Base-aa MinionPro-Bold "MinionPro-Base-Encoding-aa ReEncodeFont" <[base-MinionPro-aa.enc <MinionPro-Bold.pfb`

Comment: Could make a search in the file to see if the chain `-lf-` appears. In `…\tex\latex\MinionPro`, I have files like `T1MinionPro-LF.fd` parallel to `T1MinionPro-OsF.fd, `T1MinionPro-TLF.fd,`T1MinionPro-TOsF.fd`. Also, where exactly did you  install the MinionPro package and fonts?

Comment: @Bernard no `-lf-` appears. I followed the instruction mentioned at the top of my post. (You can view the .PDF file)

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. The problem was that the guide I mentioned at the top of the post is wrong/outdated. [The corrected version is here](https://github.com/henrikgit/MPro-Installation-Guide-GitHub).

Specifically,

Wrong:

```
C:\Users\Phil\AppData\Local\MikTeX\2.8
```

Correct:

```
C:\Users\Phil\AppData\Roaming\MikTeX\2.8
```

Wrong:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\MikTeX\2.x\fonts\type1\Adobe\MinionPro\
```

Correct:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\MikTeX\2.x\fonts\type1\Adobe\MinionPro\
```

Comment: I added the files to both of these directories (\AppData\Local\ and \AppData\Roaming\) and I still get these empty boxes. What else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

My problem with these empty boxes is even worse:

```
  \verb|\figureversion{lf,prop}|
    & \figureversion{lf,prop}0123456789 \\
  \verb|\figureversion{lf,tab}|
    & \figureversion{lf,tab}0123456789 \\
  \verb|\figureversion{osf,prop}|
    & \figureversion{osf,prop}0123456789 \\
  \verb|\figureversion{osf,tab}|
    & \figureversion{osf,tab}0123456789 \\
    
    Bold\\
    
  \verb|\figureversion{lf,prop}|
    & \figureversion{lf,prop}\textbf{0123456789} \\
  \verb|\figureversion{lf,tab}|
    & \figureversion{lf,tab}\textbf{0123456789} \\
  \verb|\figureversion{osf,prop}|
    & \figureversion{osf,prop}\textbf{0123456789} \\
  \verb|\figureversion{osf,tab}|
    & \figureversion{osf,tab}\textbf{0123456789} \\    
    
    Italic\\
    
 \verb|\figureversion{lf,prop}|
    & \figureversion{lf,prop}\textit{0123456789} \\
  \verb|\figureversion{lf,tab}|
    & \figureversion{lf,tab}\textit{0123456789} \\
  \verb|\figureversion{osf,prop}|
    & \figureversion{osf,prop}\textit{0123456789} \\
  \verb|\figureversion{osf,tab}|
    & \figureversion{osf,tab}\textit{0123456789} \\
```

Result:
[image]

How can it show the tabulars and not the linings? And how can I have bold and italic versions, but not the regular one?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).